# Помогите с import-ом Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт, python-import, python-3.10

Есть два файла:
`functions.py`

```py
from tkinter import *
from menu import button_music, background_menu_png, button_time, button_achivement, button_statistics, \
    button_exit, button_play
from pygame import mixer
import os
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:...

class Function:
    def run_stop_music_button():...


    def run_stop_music(event):...


    def run_set_time(event):...


    def run_play():...


    def run_achivement():... 


    def run_statement():...
```

и `menu.py`

```py
from tkinter import *
from pygame import mixer
from functions import Function
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:...

volume = 1
check_achivement = 0
if check_music == '1':...
elif check_music == '0':...

menu = Tk()
menu.title("Меню")
menu.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
menu.iconbitmap('textures/Logo.ico')
menu.resizable(None, None)
menu.configure(bg='grey')

if time_day == '1':
    background_menu_png = PhotoImage(file='textures/background_night.png')
elif time_day == '0':
    background_menu_png = PhotoImage(file='textures/background.png')

background_menu = Label(menu, image=background_menu_png)
background_menu.pack(side="top", fill="both")


button_play = Button(menu, text='Войти в игру',  bg='grey', fg='black', font=('pico-8', 17), command=run_play)
button_play.place(x=30, y=160, width=500, height=60)


button_exit = Button(menu, text='Выход', command=menu.quit, fg='black', bg='grey', font=('pico-8', 16))
button_exit.place(x=30, y=370, width=500, height=60)


button_statistics = Button(menu, text='Информация', command=run_statement, fg='black', bg='grey', font=('pico-8', 16))
button_statistics.place(x=30, y=230, width=500, height=60)

button_achivement = Button(menu, text='Достижения', command=run_achivement, fg='black', bg='grey', font=('pico-8', 16))
button_achivement.place(x=30, y=300, width=500, height=60)


button_time = Button(menu, text='Режим дня', command=run_set_time_button, fg='black', bg='grey', font=('pico-8', 16))
button_time.place(x=30, y=440, width=500, height=60)

button_music = Button(menu, text='Переключить музыку', command=run_stop_music_button,
                      fg='black', bg='grey', font=('pico-8', 16))
button_music.place(x=30, y=510, width=500, height=60)

menu.bind('<Control-z>', run_stop_music)
menu.bind('<Control-x>', run_set_time)
menu.mainloop()
```

Создал `functions.py` т.к. функции едят много места.
При запуске menu.py выдает следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\menu for game\menu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functions import Function
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\menu for game\functions.py", line 2, in <module>
    from menu import button_music, background_menu_png, button_time, button_achivement, button_statistics, \
  File "C:\Users\User\Downloads\menu for game\menu.py", line 3, in <module>
    from functions import Function
ImportError: cannot import name 'Function' from partially initialized module 'functions' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\User\Downloads\menu for game\functions.py)

Process finished with exit code 1.
```

Помогите решить пожалуйста.

Comment: попробуй import function а потом from function import Function

Comment: Нельзя друг из друга файлы в цикле импортировать. Импортируйте из этих двух файлов в каком-то третьем файле.

Answer (score 1):

Импорт довольно прост на самом деле. Просто помните следующее:

- `import` и `from xxx import yyy` являются исполняемыми операторами. Они выполняются, когда работающая программа достигает этой строки.
- Если модуля нет в `sys.modules`, то при импорте создается новая запись модуля в `sys.modules`, а затем выполняется код в модуле. Он не возвращает управление вызывающему модулю, пока выполнение не завершится.
- Если модуль существует в `sys.modules`, то импорт просто возвращает этот модуль независимо от того, завершилось ли его выполнение. По этой причине циклический импорт может возвращать модули, которые кажутся частично пустыми.
- Наконец, исполняемый скрипт запускается в модуле с именем `__main__`, импорт скрипта под своим именем создаст новый модуль, не связанный с `__main__`.
- Соберите все это вместе, и вы не должны столкнуться с какими-либо сюрпризами при импорте модулей.
  Попробуйте просто `import Function`, а далее вызывайте его `х= Function.functions` и так далее...

Answer (score 1):

То что вы делаете называется "циклический импорт". Решается данная проблема с помощью улучшения дизайна кода. 2 варианта:

1. объединить `functions.py` и `menu.py` в один файл
2. использовать дополнительный файл с логикой, например `main.py`, куда импортировать оба модуля

Напишу на своем примере, концепцию для второго пункта

Файл номер раз

```py
#file1.py

class File1:
    def __init__(self, name=name)
        self.name = name
    def func1(self):
        print(self.name)
```

Файл номер два

```py
#file2.py
name = "Super Hero"
```

Основная логика в `main.py`

```py
from file1 import File1
from file2 import name

example_obj = File1(name=name)
example_obj.func1()
```

Comment: Извините, дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ на второй пункт. Просто недавно столкнулся с программированием

Comment: @loganag честно лениво. плюс у меня нет понимания, почему вы в одном месте используете класс, в другом вы используете переменную, которую передаете в `finctions.py`. Такое в принципе не приемлимо.

Comment: @loganag добавил пример, обратите внимние на класс, метод `__init__`, переменные `self`. И я продолжу утверждать, что переменные передавать через импорт - плохая практика. Только если не поддерживать договоренность о константах и использовать в имени только прописные буквы